# How to upload a file to api in C# using rest sharp

Tags: c#, api, rest, restsharp

```
var client=new RestClient("URL")
var client=new RestClient("URL")
var req=new RestRequest(Method.POST)
req.AddHeader("content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=---WebKitFromBoundaryxxxx");
req.AddHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache")
req.AddHeader("Accept","application/json")
req.AddFile("SearchFile",filepathOfFile)
IRestResponse response=client.Execute(req)
```

**this is my code here my issue is i want to upload the search file. But everytime the response I am getting is "Bad request" "Required request part serachFile is not present".   I have first tested in Postman and it works in postman however when I try running this logic in C# it always fails with the error "Status": "failure", "message":"Cant create Response" "errors": [{message: "Required request part 'SearchFile' is not present"}] **

Comment: sorry, but without you showing us *your code*, there is no way we can tell what's wrong with *your code*. please *edit* your question to include the *relevant* piece of code.

Comment: A request contains headers (which are properties) and the server requires a header that is either missing or is not formed properly.